# Cython, invoking shell comand. Performance gain

Tags: python, cython

My question is simple. Is there anything to gain by using Cython vs pure Python to invoke shell commands or any other binary executables present on the OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As opposed to just `os.system()`? Not really.

[The implementation of `os.system()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2c2a4f3d8545784c6e4ca8128bfc706916080712/Modules/posixmodule.c#L4479-L4495) is basically (with some macros removed):

```
static long
os_system_impl(PyObject *module, const Py_UNICODE *command)
{
    long result;

    if (PySys_Audit("os.system", "(u)", command) < 0) {
        return -1;
    }

    result = _wsystem(command);
    return result;
}
```